# Return choose of certificate list azure VPN

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, vpn, azure-vpn

I have azure VPN and installed certificates. My colleague has installed this same but he can not choose the certificate. He hasn`t got this field. Is possible to change something in VPN to get the list of certificates?

[image]

this is working when installing cert like this (checkboxes)

[image]

Comment: Have you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441476/azure-vpn-error-a-certificate-could-not-be-found-that-can-be-used-with-this-exte) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at this [page from Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems#solution).

In a nutshell:

> This problem occurs if the client certificate is missing from Certificates - Current User\Personal\Certificates.

I believe you've already installed the certificate on the first PC that connects successfully. Still, if you need to, you can generate and export certificates as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site